# What's it called when multiple concepts are combined into a single problem?

Tags: terminology, test-design

A lot of students complain about "never being shown that before".  What's the idea called when you test multiple concepts or one or two new ones along with some old ones in a word problem, for example?  I'm trying to figure out how to articulate it so I can let the students know ahead of time that I do this during exams.

Suppose, for example, I give a word problem asking to maximize profit, a calculus concept and application they're being tested on (finding the max/min of a profit function).  They know that they need to come up with a profit function if one is not provided.  But the way I describe how to get the revenue and cost functions is not direct either - I give them enough info to determine those two functions.  And perhaps in the way that I give them that info is not like any previously assigned problems but nevertheless all they need to do is some algebra to figure out the linear or quadratic cost or revenue functions.  Of course, they also need to determine a suitable domain which again I may bury in the problem somehow.

What's this idea called that I'm doing?  Applying calculus concepts to novel situations or ...?

Comment: Perhaps [*multi-part math problems*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22multi-part+math+problems%22) or [*multi-step math problems*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22multi-step+math+problems%22).

Comment: Synthesis?${}{}$

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes, that's the word I was looking for.  It's an ability to synthesize the concepts that I'm testing.

Comment: "integrative" is also a word to describe problems or tasks that require the student to put together (integrate) different concepts in creating a solution. This term can be applied to tasks involving different concepts in a course or different disciplines.entirely.

Comment: Cross-topic exercise?

Comment: What? You want me to multiply *and* divide?

Comment: Combining ideas and asking new questions on tests is part of what I expect to see in a legitimate university education. It's really just asking them to THINK. The expectation that every problem on a test is one they have seen before is not a reasonable expectation because we seek to teach concepts and methods. Conceptual understanding extends far past the examples which illustrate the concept. They need to THINK. I realize this is at times counter-cultural.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook I completely agree.  But I also think instructors should not just give examples but exercises showing the level they expect especially for freshman courses.

Comment: @E2R0NS this is easily accomplished by posting an old test or two. Alternatively, I give a quiz before the test which is lengthy and somewhat in the same format as the soon-coming test. Time doesn't always allow for such luxury in higher courses.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Your first comment does not add to my original question IMO.  Your second is simplistic or is not imaging the scenario I'm alluding too.  And by thinking, I think you mean independence.  In either case, I sense a tone of disgust or contempt for your students.

Comment: I have respect for students who respect the concept of education. I have not as much respect for those who expect everything to be delivered on a silver platter to minimize their effort. Thinking is not the same as independence, thinking encompasses the totality of the discussion in the class and the expectation they internalize the concepts, make them their own and ultimately apply the concepts in situations foreign to the course. At least that is my ultimate goal for them. I don't disdain my students, I merely have high expectations of what they can do if they don't adopt an entitled posture

Comment: @JamesS.Cook "I have respect for students who respect the concept of education." Then you're in the wrong job  :)  Maybe independence means capable of independent learning/thought which includes internalization and application. You may be burned out since you can't control who signs up for your courses. Your expectations aren't high; they're just probably different from those of some of the students'. Your expectations seem like you're confusing school with education. What do I know though. I've always thought that most mathematicians were cowards.

Comment: I always find these sorts of problems really tricky to grade: I can easily imagine the example profit maximization accidentally measuring students' familiarity with economics. Even in the best case where all the skills being combined are skills I taught (quotient rule + chain rule + multi-step derivatives), if students are missing a piece skill (often the quotient rule) I don't really get a good measure of their multi-step derivative skills.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer I am about to give is a little tangential, but I think that it will help to answer the question "How do I communicate to *students* that the problem I am setting for them is going to require the application of several ideas, perhaps in a novel context.  My approach is related to [Bloom's taxonomy of knowledge](https://cft.vanderbilt.edu/guides-sub-pages/blooms-taxonomy/).

[image]

When I write questions (exam questions, homework questions, worksheet questions, etc), I try to put them into one of three categories:

1. **Recall:** These questions sit at the bottom of the taxonomy (roughly, "remember" and "understand").  They ask students to remember facts, regurgitate definitions, or perform very simple computations.  For example:

   > - Determine the derivative of the function $f$, given by $f(x) = x^3$.
   > - Evaluate the indefinite integral $\int \sin(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$.
   > - Complete the definition by filling in the blank:  Let $f : I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function, and let $a$ be a point in the interior of $I$.  The *derivative* of $f$ at $a$ is ____, assuming that this limit exists.

   Note that this kind of question should be answerable almost instantaneously (either you know the answer or you don't).
2. **Analysis:**  These questions sit at the middle of the pyramid ("analyze" and "apply").  They ask students to complete more complicated computations, solve equations, compare and contrast different ideas, and so on.  Typical questions are

   > - Evaluate the definite integral $\int_{0}^{1/2} \sin(\pi x)\,\mathrm{d}x$.
   > - Explain the difference between a definite integral and an indefinite integral.
   > - Determine the maximum value of the function $f$, given by $f(x) = 3x^3 - 4x + 6$ on the interval $[-2, 1]$.
   > - An open topped box is to be made by removing identical squares from each corner of a rectangle of cardboard which measures $24 \times 18$ inches (see the picture). Determine the size of square which must be removed in order to maximize the volume of the box.  [INSERT PICTURE HERE]
3. **Synthesis:**  These questions are the kind asked about in the question, and try to hit the top of the taxonomy (evaluate and create).  These questions are often beyond the level that I would expect students to be able to complete on their own (especially in an exam setting).  I usually assign these kinds of problems as homework, and encourage collaboration.  That said, there are times when they might be appropriate on an exam.

   > - The force of gravity on the moon acts to accelerate objects towards the center of the moon at a constant rate of about $-1.6$ m/s$^2$.  A golf ball is hit at an angle $45^\circ$ above horizontal with an initial velocity of $200$ m/s.  Determine the maximum height that the ball reaches.  [Note that this question would be given *before* discussing multivariable calculus—the students need to figure out for themselves that the velocity is "split" between a vertical and horizontal component.]
   > - Recall that the cosine and sine of an angle are defined to be the $x$ and $y$ coordinates (respectively) of the point where the angle intersects the unit circle.  Analogously, define the "square cosine" ($\operatorname{sqcos}$) and "square sine" ($\operatorname{sqcos}$) of an angle $\theta$ to be the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the point where the angle $\theta$ intersects a square with vertices at the points $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(-1,0)$, and $(0,-1)$.  Give formulas for $\operatorname{sqcos}$ and $\operatorname{sqsin}$ in terms other known functions (polynomials, the usual trigonometric functions, exponentials and logarithms, etc).
   > - Let $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$, and let $a$ be in the interior of $I$.
   >   The *symmetric derivative* of $f$ at $a$ is defined to be
   >   $$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x-h)}{2h}, $$ assuming that this limit exists.  Show that if $f$ is differential at $a$ (in the usual sense), then the symmetric derivative of $f$ exists at $a$, and has the same value as the usual derivative.

In communicating with students, I explicitly tell them what kind of question they are answering.  That is, I explicitly use language like "This is a recall question," or "This is a synthesis question—you might have to think about material from many different sections of the text in order to get to an answer."

So... to (kind of) answer the question:  the kinds of problems described in the original question likely fall at the high end of "analysis", or at the low end of "synthesis" (depending on how much students are supposed to create on their own, as opposed to just compile together a bunch of ideas in the process of solving the problem).

Comment: This is a nice answer. I understand that the correspondence with Bloom's Taxonomy is approximate, but how about grouping Bloom's `Remember` & `Understand` as **Comprehension** (or perhaps 'Knowledge') instead of **Recall**?

Comment: @ryang The taxonomy is meant to classify knowledge itself (so calling these "knowledge" or "comprehension" questions seems kind of out of line, as these things encompass all of the taxonomy).  The idea is to pick a description from the appropriate level of the taxonomy.  "Recall" or "Remember" or "Description" or "Identification"... something in there.  Pick your poison.

Comment: Ok I just Google-searched for “bloom’s taxonomy”, and the results generally call it Taxonomy of Learning (Objectives), not Taxonomy of Knowledge. $\quad$ Furthermore, it turns out that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom%27s_taxonomy#Cognitive_domain_(knowledge-based)) even _squarely_ agrees with my suggestion, which I’d independently developed: it says that Bloom’s original labels were (in order): **Knowledge**, **Comprehension**, **Application**, **Analysis**, **Synthesis**, **Evaluation**.

Comment: Notice that your example tasks under your first section “Recall” are actually Understanding/Comprehension rather than merely Recall tasks. (And while the higher tiers build on the lower ones, it isn’t quite accurate to frame the lowest tier as “encompassing” the entire taxonomy.)

Comment: @ryang From the site I linked in my answer:  "**Knowledge** 'involves the recall of specifics and universals, the recall of methods and processes, or the recall of a pattern, structure, or setting.'"  Notice the repeated use of the term "recall".  I would also argue that the tasks I have given *are* recall tasks, as identities like $\int \sin(x) = \cos(x) + C$ *ought* to be rote tasks for a calculus student.

Comment: It should also be noted that *a lot* of work has been done since Bloom, and that the modern understanding of the taxonomy (and how to use and apply it) has moved away from Bloom's original work, focusing more on "verbs," for example.  See https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Taxonomy_for_Learning_Teaching_and_Ass/bcQlAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0&bsq=0321084055  or https://cft.vanderbilt.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/59/BloomsTaxonomy-mary-forehand.pdf .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147273/discussion-between-xander-henderson-and-ryang).

Comment: By "not merely Recall tasks", I mean that the tasks in the blue to red tiers build on Recall, not that they exclude Recall. (Needless to say, Comprehension, Analysis, Synthesis all involve Recall.) Anyhoo. This is a nice, useful answer (save for my nitpick).

Answer (score 4):

Many textbooks simply identify these as "Applications".

Of course, the more bits and pieces that need to be pulled in and synthesized for a problem, the more challenging it will be. Some books mark increasing difficulty of exercises in this way in some fashion (often A-B-C level exercises or the like).

The general idea of practicing old skills interleaved with new ones is called ["Mixed Practice"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varied_practice) (or "Varied Practice"), but that more often refers to a series of small, separate exercises on a variety of skills.

Answer (score 0):

A related concept is Rich Math Tasks (https://www.doe.virginia.gov/teaching-learning-assessment/k-12-standards-instruction/mathematics/instructional-resources/rich-mathematical-task) -- activities that require math students to pull in many different levels of thinking (as Xander points out), as well as multiple areas of the course. Getting students familiar with performing these tasks before an exam can help improve student readiness for novel problems on test day.